# Creating a window-relative DeviceContext on multiple monitors

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I'm working on a legacy (1999) codebase, which has an annoying bug where scrolling in some GUI elements doesn't redraw properly when the window is placed on a non-primary monitor.

As far as I can make out (not being very familiar with Windows's APIs) the problem is that the code fetches the DeviceContext to draw to using `GetDC(hwnd)`, which from what I can make out of the docs gets a DC for the primary monitor only (but the docs aren't terribly clear, TBH).

I've managed to draw things on the screen, using basically:

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromRect(&rect, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
MONITORINFOEX minfo;
minfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &minfo);
HDC = CreateDC(NULL, minfo.szDevice, NULL, NULL);
```

This gets things drawn to the correct monitor, but the application clearly expects something that's window-relative, because everything ends up in the top-left corner of the desktop and not in the window.

Now, my googling seems to indicate that running the paint code twice using `EnumDisplayMonitors(GetDC(), &rect, PaintCallback, NULL)` should do the right thing. Unfortunately, my code isn't C or C++. It's a SmallTalk image (and support ended 15 years ago or so, so complaining to the vendor is out), and I'm simply not sure if the paint handling happens in code that I have access to, or if it's deep enough in the guts of the SmallTalk that I can't get to it.

Thus my question: is it possible to create a DC that's relative to my window's client area (by tweaking the DC from CreateDC perhaps)? I realize this will probably break if the window straddles two monitors, but that's at least less broken than the current state of things.

UPDATE:

I've managed to run the rendering code twice, using `EnumDisplayMonitors`, but that crashes in weird ways (which is most likely a SmallTalk problem; the compiler is old and idiosyncratic, but debugging code this deep in the stack is problematic).

To answer the comments: I think the code basically wants to draw on windows, yes. The SmallTalk objects representing the various GUI elements carry around window handles that are used to create DCs with `GetDC(hwnd)`, so that's easy enough. So it sounds like `GetDC(hwnd)` *should* get a DC that does the right thing, in this case; it could be that the ST code is caching the DCs somewhere and `GetDC` will return a different DC when the window is moved to a different screen (which sounds plausible from my cursory knowledge of this).

Comment: Looks like you want to draw on some window. Use `FindWindow` to get a window handle, or use Spy++ utility in Visual Studio to find the window handle. Create the DC: `HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd)`, and call `ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)` when finished. But this is a cheap hack of course, your drawings will be erased very quickly. Why don't you do it properly by creating your own window?

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to GetDC itself. Maybe there is also some code that uses GetClientRect/GetWindowRect and the coordinates are taken relative to primary screen somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was indeed caching of the DCs created by `GetDC`. I hacked the rendering code to not use the caches (more or less, the code is a bit tangled), and from a first look it looks like that did the trick.

For posterity, in case someone googles for Visual Smalltalk Enterprise and finds this answer, what I did was to edit `GraphicsTool>>ifNilHandle:` to not actually check if the handle is nil, but always run the block to get a fresh handle and return true at the end. This way, fresh DCs are fetched every time.

UPDATE:

This fixes the immediate problem I was trying to fix, but unfortunately breaks a couple of other things (most notably WindowBuilder Pro, the GUI construction tool-kit). The problem is clearly over-eager caching of DCs somewhere in the code, but it needs to be fixed in a much more focussed manner than the sledgehammer approach above.